# How to delete part of a MySQL database record?

Tags: mysql

I want to delete part of a record. For example, a column called "message" contains the following string:

"Hi, My name is John"

I want to delete just "John" from the above while retaining the "Hi, My name is" part in tact.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```sql
UPDATE SomeTable SET message = REPLACE(message, "John", "") WHERE id = 123;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't delete anything; the row is updated.

```
UPDATE table_name SET
message = "Hi, My name is"
WHERE message = "Hi, My name is John"
```